# How does versioning happen in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am using ionic 3 and while adding any Cordova plugin I don't specify any version. 
How is the compatibility of plugins between ionic 4 and ionic 3 projects maintained and how is it determined which version of the plugin is installed?

An example:

> I installed native http

```
npm install @ionic-native/http

npm WARN @ionic-native/http@5.2.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/http@5.2.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I'm told to add incompatible ionic 4 plugins in my ionic 3 project. How can I determine the best stable release for ionic 3?

Comment: Do you mean ionic-native or cordova? ionic-native acts as the wrapper and its versioning matters. Not sure if cordova plugin version itself is an issue for ionic .

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to install Ionic `http` native module. Each Ionic version (3 & 4) has its documentation page.

- For Ionic 3, available here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/, you need to do:

```
$> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$> npm install --save @ionic-native/http@4
```

- For Ionic 4, available here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http:

```
$> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$> npm install @ionic-native/http
```

Hope I help!